# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first')

Tags: reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, next.js

I am trying to add data to a dynamic form in antd.
I get the data from firebase and use useEffect to get it.
When I try to run my code I get the error TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'first')
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal

Here is what I have

```
  const availablelinks = {

    links: [
      alllinks
    ]
  };



      <Form.List name="links" initialValue={
        availablelinks.links.map((item) => {
          console.log(item[0])
          const lol = item[0]['first']
          const zol = 'zol'
          return {
            first: lol,
            last: zol,
          };  
        
    
      }, [])


      }>
```

here is the rest of my code https://wtools.io/paste-code/bEEc .
I think that the error has something to do with the useEffect (because when I edit the code and next.js updates the code in the browser there is nothing happening but when I refresh I get the error)
For reference here is how the form looks :
[image]

Now i am using

```
const [theArray, setTheArray] = useState([]);
... (see full code)
      <Form.List name="links" initialValue={
        theArray.map((item) => {
          console.log(item)
          const lol = item.first
          const zol = item.last
          return {
            first: lol,
            last: zol,
          };  
        
    
      }, [])


      }>
```

and I get https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XZ0e.jpg (it kinda works)
it get the state when it is changes but the form does not update

Comment: The only reason such an issue occurs is when the item[0] is undefined so it gives error trying to get ['first'] for an "undefined" object, and I think the console.log should also be saying that the item[0] is undefined.

Comment: it is undefined for the first time it does the request, for some reason it does 3 requests : https://imgur.com/a/SZa5Dc4 @dev404